# Access data of class in class

Tags: ios, swift2, realm

I have this classes:

```
class FacebookDB: Object {
    dynamic var userName: String = ""
    dynamic var profilePicture: String = ""
}

class TwitterDB: Object {
    dynamic var userName: String = ""
    dynamic var profilePicture: String = ""
}

class UserDB: Object {
    dynamic var id = 0

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }

    dynamic var userName: String = ""
    dynamic var firstName: String = ""
    dynamic var lastName: String = ""
    dynamic var email: String = ""
    dynamic var facebookAccount = FacebookDB?()
    dynamic var twitterAccount = TwitterDB?()
}
```

After I put a value inside the `userName`

```
//user value come from facebook
let testUser = UserDB()
let realm = try! Realm()

testUser.FacebookAccount?.userName = user.userName

print(user.userName)
print(testUser.FacebookAccount?.userName)
```

Here is the output:

```
vivieng
nil
```

Why can't I print `testUser.FacebookAccount?.userName`?

BTW I can access every value from `UserDB` but none of `FacebookDB` nor `TwitterDB`, any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found how to deal with this.

I need to create a value like that:

```
let facebookAccount = FacebookDB()
```

And then put everything I want inside:

```
facebookAccount.userName = user.userName
```

And finally copy the class inside the class:

```
testUser.FacebookAccount = facebookAccount
```

And voilà, that's work now!